# Mass editing contact's birthdays

Tags: contacts, profile, batches

Due to problem on our end we have about 13 000 contacts with "01.01.1970" as their birthday. I'd like to remove that from all those contacts, and tried doing that by using "Batch Update via Profile". I made a simple profile with only birth date, but it doesn't seem to work.

Firstly I have to manually type in the birth date (calender drop down doesn't work), and using the copy button doesn't work. Changes are not saved either.

Does anyone know of another way to mass edit birth dates, or does anyone know how to fix this bug? I'm quite new at CiviCRM so I might have done something wrong.

Comment: You talk of 'mass edit' but think you mean 'mass removal'

Answer (score 2):

With that many contacts whose records all need changing, I think I'd be inclined to let them do it themselves.  You could send them each an email with an editable profile including date of birth (required).  You could include a checksum to save them having to login and the profile form would then be pre-filled.  This could be a good time to keep their profiles up to date.

You dont say which CMS you are using but a useful link to token checksums is at https://wiki.civicrm.org/confluence/display/CRMDOC/Tokens.

Checksum for standard Profiles (edit mode): To send people to a profile use this path where N is the ID of the Profile you want to send them to:

```
Drupal: http://www.myorganization.org/civicrm/profile/edit?reset=1&gid=N&{contact.checksum}&id={contact.contact_id}
Joomla!: http://www.myorganization.org/index.php?option=com_civicrm&task=civicrm/profile/edit&reset=1&gid=N&{contact.checksum}&id={contact.contact_id}
WordPress: http://www.myorganization.org/?page=CiviCRM&q=civicrm/profile/edit&reset=1&gid=N&{contact.checksum}&id={contact.contact_id}
```

Hope this helps.

Answer (score 2):

Talk to your IT support. This can fixed in 5 minutes with some straightforward SQL (structured query language)

Answer (score 0):

Thank you for the answers! The checksum thing might be helpful later.

But I figured out the problem, in the birth date field there was a checkbox crossed that said show only/read only.

Cheers